# Get Sonar host url in Plugin Code (for REST calls)

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I'm working on a Sonar Plugin where I need to make some REST calls inside the Sensor/Decorator. How do I get the URL of the Sonar Host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to the Server base URL (Settings - General)
I did it like this:

```
settings.getString("sonar.core.serverBaseURL")
```

sonar.core.serverBaseURL is the key for the setting.

This returns http://localhost:9000 on my local test-machine. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get the Settings from the DecoratorContext aswell?

Comment: Is there an (exhaustive) list of Settings to get? How would someone starting a Plugin know to the "sonar.core.serverBaseURL" String?

Comment: Maybe `settings.getProperties()` will help, I've never used it before. 

Afaik, there are no settings for DecoratorContext.
Why would you need that, anyway?

Comment: I want to create a plugin that monitors the changes of individual test cases (not just the entire file or project). So I use the REST api/test/show to get the duration from the last run and compare it with the duration from the current run. The SureFirePlugin gets the testCase execution time (for Java), so I need to make my analysis in the Decorator phase. My current work-around is to get the Base URL in the Sensor, save it in a static variable and access it from the decorators.

Comment: Add a variable for settings and add/extend the constructor for the decorator by Settings:
`private final Settings settings;

public TestDecorator(Settings settings) {
   this.settings = settings;
}`

Then you can access the settings...

Comment: Thanks you so much! It would be great to get your insight on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278275/sonar-plugin-development-workflow).

Comment: May I know which specific Settings class is being discussed here?