# Sonar Plugin Development Workflow

Tags: sonarqube, workflow, development-environment

How do I setup a decent debug workflow for Sonar Plugin Development. Currently it looks like this ->

mvn clean install the plugin
copy jar over to the Sonar folder
restart Sonar Server (takes way too long for decent workflow)
run mvndebug sonar:sonar in my example project
run remote debug in IntelliJ

I've read some stuff about the [Development Mode and how nice it all works with JRebel](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/sonarqube-plugins-4/) but I can't find anything that's compatible with 4.5 or the any of the newer Versions (when they renamed Sonar to SonarQube).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal solution...

I still do it like this:

1. Build plugin
2. Deploy on local SQ and start server (batch script)
3. Test with actual projects